# error:does not contain a definition for '' and no extension method

Tags: c#

My code is giving this error

> 'Net.Kniaz.AHP.AHPModel' does not contain a definition for 'AddCriteria' and no extension method 'AddCriteria' accepting a first argument of type 'Net.Kniaz.AHP.AHPModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

and I don't know what the problem is. I reviewed several similar question, but still couldn't find a solution.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using DotNetMatrix;
using GeneralMatrix;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Net.Kniaz.AHP;

namespace Net.Kniaz.AHP
{
 public class AHPModel
 {
     public AHPModel(int n, int m);     

     private GeneralMatrix _criteria;
     private GeneralMatrix _choiceMatrix;
     private GeneralMatrix _orderedCriteria;
     private GeneralMatrix _calculatedChoices;
     private int _ncriteria;
     private int _mchoice;
     private int _superDim;
  }
public class TestAHP
{
public void TestVacationSpotSelection()
{
        double[][] criteria = new double[][]
                            { 
            new double[]       {1,5,0.33333333,1},
            new double[] {0,1,0.2,0.5},
            new double[] {0,0,1,3},
            new double[] {0,0,0,1}
                            };

        double[][] activitiesChoices = new double[][]
            {
                new double[] {1,4,3},
                new double[] {0,1,2},
                new double[] {0,0,1}
            };

        double[][] nightlifeChoices = new double[][]
            {
                new double[] {1,0.5,0.3333333},
                new double[] {0,1,0.5},
                new double[] {0,0,1}
            };

        double[][] siteseeingChoices = new double[][]
            {
                new double[] {1,0.142857,0.2},
                new double[] {0,1,2},
                new double[] {0,0,1}
            };

        double[][] costChoices = new double[][]
            {
                new double[] {1,3,5},
                new double[] {0,1,2},
                new double[] {0,0,1}
            };

        //4 criteria, 3 choices


        AHPModel model = new AHPModel(4,3);
        model.AddCriteria(criteria);
        model.AddCriterionRatedChoices(0,activitiesChoices);
        model.AddCriterionRatedChoices(1,nightlifeChoices);
        model.AddCriterionRatedChoices(2,siteseeingChoices);
        model.AddCriterionRatedChoices(3,costChoices);

        model.CalculateModel();

        GeneralMatrix calcCriteria = model.CalculatedCriteria;
        GeneralMatrix results = model.ModelResult;
        GeneralMatrix choices = model.CalculatedChoices;
        //choices: SF 42%, Orlando31%, NY 27%


Assert.AreEqual(31,System.Math.Round(choices.GetElement(0,0)*100,0));
Assert.AreEqual(42,System.Math.Round(choices.GetElement(1,0)*100,0));
Assert.AreEqual(27,System.Math.Round(choices.GetElement(2,0)*100,0));
```

The error is in the lines (5 to 13) lines from the end (model).

Answer (score 2):

your class AHPModel obviously does not have a method AddCriteria...

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use a piece of code that doesn't exist.

```
 public class AHPModel
 {
 public AHPModel(int n, int m); 
 private GeneralMatrix _criteria;
 private GeneralMatrix _choiceMatrix;
 private GeneralMatrix _orderedCriteria;
 private GeneralMatrix _calculatedChoices;
 private int _ncriteria;
 private int _mchoice;
 private int _superDim;
/*private void AddCriteria(object o);*/ //<-ghost code
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me exactly what should I do , i'm a beginner

Comment: actually what I was trying to do is to use this project to reference another project that was not executable, so this part does exist in the other project